# Update value by 1 in Firestore doc (javascript/React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore database is structured like so:

[image]

I'm trying to update a "likes" field in the `palettes` collection in a Firestore doc with an `onClick` event and not having any luck.

I'm passing the `name` field (in this case "Testing") to my `onClick` handler to get the Firestore `doc` ref and then trying to update that doc's 'likes' field value by 1.

Here is my `onClick` handler:

```
const handleLike = name => {
    // name is "Testing"
    let palette = db.collection('palettes').doc(name)

    palette.update({
        likes: // what goes here??
    })

}
```

How can I increment the `likes` field value for the given palette doc?

Maybe this is not the way to go about it but if I have lots of palette docs, I'd like to avoid having to read in the entire collection to update it each time.

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about the `increment` option.

Comment: And I got it sorted. Thanks for the help.